# Eqnumbering with polyglossia

Tags: equations, polyglossia, ntheorem

This short code results in an equation enumerated with italic font when the equation is inside a `theorem` environment. How to get it written by normal font? If I delete the segment `\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}`, then I get what I need, but I need this segment to be in the preamble, so any other solution would help.

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, ntheorem}

\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}

\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}[Mapping=ascii-to-serbian, Script=Cyrillic, Language=Serbian]{DejaVu Serif}
%\newfontfamily{\serbianfonttt}{DejaVu Serif}

\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}Th.....

    \begin{equation}
    a=b
    \end{equation}
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `mathtools` and `ntheorem`: I define a tag style which does the job, and incorporate it in theorem-like environments with the `\theoremprework` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, ntheorem}

\newtagform{thm}{\upshape(}{)}

\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}

\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}[Mapping=ascii-to-serbian, Script=Cyrillic, Language=Serbian]{DejaVu Serif}
%\newfontfamily{\serbianfonttt}{DejaVu Serif}
\theoremprework{\usetagform{thm}}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}Th.....
    \begin{equation}
    a=b
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works perfectly. THX!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a bug in Polyglossia, which redefines `\normalfont` (it has to), but not to the point it imposes upright shape and medium series.

For instance, `\textbf{abc\normalfont def}` would print everything in boldface.

I'm not completely sure the patch I propose is the best, but in the particular case it works.

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, ntheorem}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xpatch} % for the following patch

\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}

% the patch to the redefined \normalfont
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xapptocmd\normalfont
  {\fontshape{\shapedefault}%
   \fontseries{\seriesdefault}%
   \selectfont}
  {}{}%
}

\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}[
  Mapping=ascii-to-serbian,
  Script=Cyrillic,
  Language=Serbian,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{DejaVuSerif}
%\newfontfamily{\serbianfonttt}{DejaVu Serif}

\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]


\begin{document}

\textbf{abc\normalfont def}

\begin{theorem}
Th.....
\begin{equation}
    a=b
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]